# Data Sanitization - Guess the number

Tags: c++

I'm coding a game where the computer has to guess the number you are thinking of. My data sanitization only works if you enter the wrong string for the first time. Suppose you enter a wrong string a second time the data sanitization breaks. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string hint, play;
    int max = 100, min = 0, tries=0, num;
    bool again;
    again = true;
    
    while(again = true){
        do {
            num = (max + min) / 2;
            cout<< "The computer's guess is: " << num << endl;
            cout << "Is your number higher, lower, or correct?: ";
            cin >> hint;
            
                if(hint !="lower"){
                    if(hint != "higher"){
                        if(hint!="correct"){
                            cout << "Is your number higher, lower, or correct?: ";
                            cin >> hint; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            tries++;
            
            if (hint == "higher")
                min = num + 1;
            else if (hint == "lower")
                max = num - 1;
            else
            cout << "The computer's guess was correct after " << tries<<endl;
            
        }while(hint != "correct");

    cout << "do you want to play again?(y/n): ";
    cin>>play;
    
        if(play!="y"){
            if(play!="n"){
            cout << "do you want to play again?(y/n): ";
            cin>>play;
            }
        }
    
    if(play == "y"){
        again = true;
    }
    if(play == "n"){
        cout<<"thank you for playing";
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to run something multiple times, you use a loop. You've already used one `while` loop, so make another one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using a while loop instead of a nested if statement. This way we wait until the user decides to enter the correct input. Also, it is generally a good idea to convert the user's input to lowercase and remove spaces in case they type something like this `" CorRecT"`. Users will never type exactly what you expect them to as a general rule of thumb.

The code I provided needs the include `<algorithm>` to work properly. If you can't add it for some reason, just remove the line that starts with `transform`. The string won't have whitespace removed if you do that.

 I also changed the line `while (again = true)` to `while (again)`. Using the `=` operator would set the value of `again` to `true`, which I assume is unintended. The `==` operator is probably what you were looking for. However, there is no point in checking equality to `true` in any if statement or loop, as the loop will always run if the condition is equal to true.

```
 while (again) {
        do {
            num = (max + min) / 2;
            cout << "The computer's guess is: " << num << endl; \
            bool invalidInput = true;
            while (invalidInput) {
                cout << "Is your number higher, lower, or correct?: ";
                cin >> hint;
                // Remove whitespace and convert hint to lowercase
                hint.erase(remove_if(hint.begin(), hint.end(), isspace), hint.end());
                transform(hint.begin(), hint.end(), hint.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return tolower(c); });

                // Validate the input
                if (hint == "higher" || hint == "lower" || hint == "correct") {
                    invalidInput = false;
                }
            }

            ...
    }
```